# Change a Page's Header Image

Tags: pages, css, header-image

I am using [Sunrise Theme](http://www.s5themes.com/documentation/sunrise/) from s5themes.com , and I was wondering if in the individual pages I can have a different Header Image, because from what I can tell they use the same CSS code in displaying the header image on the Home Page.

Here is the screenshot of the Home page showing the Image as header

[image]

And here is the screenshot of the a Page (About Us) which uses the same Image (the brown texture with green part) as header only seemed zoomed-in.

[image]

I tried digging into the code and I believe this is the part in the Styles.css that deals with it.

**CSS**

```
.header-wrapper {
background: #333;
background-image: url(img/wood-only.png);
background-attachment: fixed;
background-size: cover;
min-height: 200px;
```

So I edited the code above, unfortunately it also affects the Image in the Home page
I tried setting the background-size into

```
background-size: auto;
```

Ideally I can work with editing the template files but I am not familiar with WordPress' structure, and now I am not sure how to procede.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve this without relying too much on creating new templates, by using JetPack plugin.

And took advantage of it's ability to add Custom CSS

This is the **CSS** line I added

```
body.page .header-wrapper {
    background: #333;
    background-image: url(http://image-url/image.png);
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: auto !important;
    min-height: 200px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The body tag has quite a few classes eg "home page page-id-### page-template page-template-template-name" you could make use of to customize the header with css. Just specify a different target:

```
.home .header-wrapper {
   background-image: url(img/some-other-image.png);
}
```

Comment: It's important to note that the theme has to use the function [`body_class()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/body_class)

Comment: @MikeNGarrett Thank you for giving me an insight on how to solve this.

What I did was make use of JetPack's Custom CSS, added the CSS code there.